# how to launch floating icon in when dialer open

Tags: android, android-service

I have developed an a floating icon app. when the start service button click. the service start and floating icon float on all screen. But i want only when the dialer app launch the floating icon service will start. Other wise, it will stop the service.

Comment: post, if possible, some code snippet. that way you'll give people better info about your issue.

Comment: http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/

Comment: This is the tutorial website : [link](http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/). In this tutorial the floating icon is shown in all screen. I want only to show the floating icon when dialer open. or only start service when dialer open.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> FloatingActionbutton

Here I am providing a link of tutorial:
[www.guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons](http://www.guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons)

Comment: I don't want floatting action button (FAB). I want how when a dialer open that time a service start. That means, how to start a service when current default application (example dialer) open.